# affect parent element by hover on child

Tags: html, css, sass

Let's say I have smthg like that:

```html
<div class="bigWrap">
    <div class="element">
        ...
        <div class="HoverThisElement"></div>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        ...
        <div class="HoverThisElement"></div>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        ...
        <div class="HoverThisElement"></div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And I need to affect .element when his child .HoverThisElement is hovered. Can I do that? Please give example with SASS if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workaround using CSS using `pointer-events`. This might help.

```css
.element {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.HoverThisElement {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 15px;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.element:hover {
  background: green; //add some styles you want to parent element
}
```

```html
<div class="bigWrap">
  <div class="element">

    <div class="HoverThisElement"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="element">

    <div class="HoverThisElement"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="element">

    <div class="HoverThisElement"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like "little_coder" said you can trick this.

But when you want to support IE10 (no pointer-events support) you can just use an overlay DIV and target it with the sibling selector (You could use a pseudo element, too).

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.HoverThisElement {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 3;

    &:hover {
        + .overlay {
            right: 200px;
        }
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/herrfischer/pen/xxKEjqR

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to do that in CSS because there are no parent [selectors in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/).

If you really need to do that, the only way is to use JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

As Logan said there is not parent selector, you need to do the following: on "HoverThisElement" mouse in add class active to closest "element", on mouse out remove active class